# Magento 2: Order Information Attachment with Order Email

Tags: orders, sales-order, order-email, email-attachment

I have created a module which is used to send order information as attachment in order email like invoice attachment in invoice mail. I got order attachment in order email but I can't get Order items information in attachment. When I went through the process, I got order template variables of type interceptor like get_class(vars['order']) = Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor. So, How could I get template variable as type of order model.

Here, is my Code...

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder">
        <plugin name="vendor_order_invoice_attachment" type="Vendor\OrderInvoiceAttachment\Plugin\SendAttachment" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessage">
        <plugin name="vendor-attachment-mimemessage" type="Vendor\OrderInvoiceAttachment\Plugin\MimeMessage"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**SendAttachment.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\OrderInvoiceAttachment\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory;

class SendAttachment
{
    public $attachmentManager;
    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\OrderInvoiceAttachment\Model\AttachmentManager $attachmentManager
    )
    {
        $this->attachmentManager = $attachmentManager;
    }

    public function beforeSetTemplateIdentifier($subject, $templateId)
    {
        $this->attachmentManager->resetParts();
        $this->attachmentManager->setTemplateId($templateId);
        return [$templateId];
    }

    public function beforeSetTemplateVars($subject, $templateVars)
    {
        $this->attachmentManager->setTemplateVars($templateVars);
        return [$templateVars];
    }
}
```

**AttachmentManager.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\OrderInvoiceAttachment\Model;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\InvoiceIdentity;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity;

class AttachmentManager
{
    public $scopeConfig;

    public $invoicePdf;
    public $orderPdf;

    public $mimePartInterfaceFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice $invoicePdf,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\MimePartInterfaceFactory $mimePartInterfaceFactory,
        \Vendor\OrderInvoiceAttachment\Model\OrderPdf $orderPdf
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->invoicePdf = $invoicePdf;
        $this->orderPdf = $orderPdf;
        $this->mimePartInterfaceFactory = $mimePartInterfaceFactory;
    }

    private $templateId;

    private $templateVars = [];

    private $parts = null;

    public function setTemplateId($templateId)
    {
        $this->templateId = $templateId;
    }

    public function setTemplateVars($templateVars)
    {
        $this->templateVars = $templateVars;
    }

    public function getTemplateId()
    {
        return $this->templateId;
    }

    public function getTemplateVars()
    {
        return $this->templateVars;
    }

    public function resetParts()
    {
        $this->parts = null;
    }

    public function getParts()
    {
        return $this->parts;
    }

    public function addPart($part)
    {
        $this->parts[] = $part;
    }

    public function collectParts()
    {
        $this->parts = [];
        if ($this->templateId === 'sales_email_order_template') {
            $orderTemplateId = $this->getConfigValue(
                OrderIdentity::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
                $this->getStoreId()
            );

            $guestOrderTemplateId = $this->getConfigValue(
                OrderIdentity::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE,
                $this->getStoreId()
            );

            switch ($this->getTemplateId()) {
                case $orderTemplateId:
                case $guestOrderTemplateId:
                    $this->attachOrderPDF();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if ($this->templateId === 'sales_email_invoice_template') {
            $invoiceTemplateId = $this->getConfigValue(
                InvoiceIdentity::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
                $this->getStoreId()
            );

            $guestInvoiceTemplateId = $this->getConfigValue(
                InvoiceIdentity::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE,
                $this->getStoreId()
            );

            switch ($this->getTemplateId()) {
                case $invoiceTemplateId:
                case $guestInvoiceTemplateId:
                    $this->attachInvoicePDF();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public function getStoreId()
    {
        $vars = $this->getTemplateVars();
        if (!isset($vars['store'])) {
            return null;
        }

        $store = $vars['store'];
        return $store->getId();
    }

    public function getConfigValue($path, $store = null)
    {
        return $configValue = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $store
        );
    }

    public function attachInvoicePDF()
    {
        $vars = $this->getTemplateVars();
        $invoice = $vars['invoice'];

        $fileContent = $this->invoicePdf->getPdf([$invoice])->render();
        $fileName = 'invoice.pdf';

        $attachmentPart = $this->mimePartInterfaceFactory->create(
            [
                'content' => $fileContent,
                'type' => 'application/pdf',
                'fileName' => $fileName,
                'disposition' => \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                'encoding' => \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64
            ]
        );

        $this->addPart($attachmentPart);
    }
    public function attachOrderPDF()
    {
        $vars = $this->getTemplateVars();
        $order = $vars['order'];
        $fileContent = $this->orderPdf->getPdf([$order])->render();
        $fileName = 'order.pdf';

        $attachmentPart = $this->mimePartInterfaceFactory->create(
            [
                'content' => $fileContent,
                'type' => 'application/pdf',
                'fileName' => $fileName,
                'disposition' => \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                'encoding' => \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64
            ]
        );

        $this->addPart($attachmentPart);
    }
}
```

**OrderPdf.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\OrderInvoiceAttachment\Model;


use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;
use Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager;

class OrderPdf extends AbstractPdf
{

    protected $_localeResolver;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $factory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        Config $pdfConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_localeResolver = $localeResolver;
        parent::__construct(
            $paymentData,
            $string,
            $scopeConfig,
            $filesystem,
            $pdfConfig,
            $pdfTotalFactory,
            $pdfItemsFactory,
            $localeDate,
            $inlineTranslation,
            $addressRenderer,
            $data
        );
    }

    protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
        /* Add table head */
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 15);
        $this->y -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0, 0, 0));

        //columns headers
        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Products'), 'feed' => 35];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('SKU'), 'feed' => 290, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Qty'), 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Price'), 'feed' => 360, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Tax'), 'feed' => 495, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Subtotal'), 'feed' => 565, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 5];

        $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->y -= 20;
    }


    public function getPdf($orders = [])
    {
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

        $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
        $this->_setPdf($pdf);
        $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            if ($order->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->emulate($order->getStoreId());
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($order->getStoreId());
            }
            $page = $this->newPage();
            /* Add image */
            $this->insertLogo($page, $order->getStore());
            /* Add address */
            $this->insertAddress($page, $order->getStore());
            /* Add head */
            $this->insertOrder(
                $page,
                $order,
                $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                    self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $order->getStoreId()
                )
            );
            /* Add document text and number */
            $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Order # ') . $order->getIncrementId());
            /* Add table */
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
            /* Add body */
            foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */
                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }
            /* Add totals */
            $this->insertTotals($page, $order);
            if ($order->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->revert();
            }
        }
        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        return $pdf;
    }

    public function newPage(array $settings = [])
    {
        /* Add new table head */
        $page = $this->_getPdf()->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $this->_getPdf()->pages[] = $page;
        $this->y = 800;
        if (!empty($settings['table_header'])) {
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
        }
        return $page;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override  \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="TM\ShipmentEmail\Model\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>
```

Define this constant if you need in overrides file and add following data

```
const MIME_TYPES = [
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'jpg' => 'image/jpg'
    ];
    
  //check file type  
protected function prepareMessage()
{
$snapshotFileTypes = self::MIME_TYPES[ (string) substr($snapshot, strrpos($snapshot, '.') + 1); ];

 //call for attachment in custom function    
        $this->addAttachment(file_get_contents($fullSnapshotPath), $endSnap, $snapshotFileType );
}
       // finally add attachment in this funtion

        public function addAttachment(?string $content, ?string $fileName, ?string $fileType)
        {
            $attachmentPart = $this->partFactory->create();
            $attachmentPart->setContent($content)
                ->setType($fileType)
                ->setFileName($fileName)
                ->setDisposition(Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT)
                ->setEncoding(Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);
            $this->attachments[] = $attachmentPart;
    
            return $this;
        }
```